# Is the Monoprice Tablet a good investment?

Tags: drawing-tablet, hardware-recommendation, hardware, wacom

I'm planning do to some serious animating and drawing this summer so I've been considering buying a cintiq 13HD. The pad tablet works, but it's not the same feeling as drawing on papers which is why I think I want a cintiq or a LCD screen.

Is there any guy using this LCD tablet?

http://www.monoprice.com/product?c_id=108&cp_id=10841&cs_id=1084101&p_id=14481&seq=1&format=2

It's very considerable price relative to cintiq.

Also bigger screen but not Wacom.

Comment: These Not-Wacom drawing displays have a tendency to be kinda iffy. It could work perfectly, but people often report stuff like: suddenly stopped working, difficult to setup, compatibility issues and terrible support. But then again, same size Cintiq would cost 3 times as much... It the price was $200 I'd get it, but I don't know. $600 is a lot to pay for something, if it ends up going belly up.

Comment: As a side note, I personally hate that "paper texture" or what ever. To me it feels like it's just a marketing ploy. Kinda like having the eraser on the other end. Like: "Wow! Just flip the pen around to erase!", but literally nobody uses it. The paper texture, in my opinion, is only good for wearing out your pen nibs in a day or two. With a clear surface you can go with one pen nib for years... and even if I forget about that, I enjoy the feel of the smooth surface way more.

Comment: I use the eraser, but admittedly not that much. Personally i think the problem with the erases is in application support.

Comment: Here here @Joonas and if you (oddly) *happen to actually like* that horrible "paper-feel" surface, guess what? When it gets worn smooth, it's a **repair** to get it replaced. You can't just buy a new surface sheet like all the previous models. $$$ ploy for sure. I wore my tablet smooth in a few weeks and went through 4 or 5 nibs... since that first month or so, I've been using the same nib for literally 2 years. -- as for tablets in general -- **Get a Wacom, or don't bother getting anything.** (Adobe *only tests against Wacom devices.*)